# What do I put in <h1> in a blog homepage?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

In my blog's homepage there are the latest articles, their titles within `<h2>` tags and there aren't any `<h1>` tags in homepage. But, there's no title to put in an `<h1>` tag because my blog's title is a logo within an `<img>` tag in the header and when is the article page, the article's title is the `<h1>`. So, what should I do?

1) Put my logo in `<h1>` and article titles in `<h2>`.
2) Keep with my logo in the header and create an `<h1>` with a title like "My blog's homepage" and hide it with CSS to only search engines find it and put article titles in `<h2>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 2.**
For SEO purposes and for screen readers, it is important that you have that h1 tag filled out. Hiding it with CSS will still allow screen readers to see it.